# How to import platform specific file in flutter?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I am using [JS package](https://pub.dev/packages/js) for `Flutter to JS` communication and vice versa.
It's working fine when I try to run on the web but giving errors when trying to run in the mobile emulator.

I am trying this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'
if(dart.library.jqyery) 'common.dart';
```

But that starts giving errors on all the functions which are in file `common. dart`

This is `common. dart`

```
@JS()
library jquery;

import 'globals.dart';
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('myCallDartToJSFunction')
external void myAlert(String str);

@JS('connectToSignalR')
external void connectToSignalR();

@JS("mySendMsgTSignalR")
external void myDartSendMsgTSignalR(String nam, String msg);

@JS('myCallJSToDart')
external set _myCallJSToDart(void Function(String str, int x) f);

@JS()
external void myCallJSToDart(String str, int x);

void _someDartFunction(String str, int x) {
  print(str + x.toString());
  msgFromSignalr = str;
}

@JS('messageFromSignalR')
external set _messageFromSignalR(void Function(String str) f);

@JS()
external void messageFromSignalR();

String _dartmessageFromSignalR(String str) {

}

void bindmain() {
  _myCallJSToDart = allowInterop((text, x) => _someDartFunction(text, x));
  _messageFromSignalR = allowInterop((str) => _dartmessageFromSignalR(str));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are importing `flutter/material.dart` when you are on mobile which won't be accepted as a valid replacement for `common.dart`. When doing conditionnal imports you should **always provide 2 identical implementations**. In your case it means making a file, for example, `common_mobile.dart` which will implement the same methods that are in your `common.dart` but doing nothing (or even throwing an UnimplementedException) as they should not be called while you are on mobile.

I see that you are making a library inside your `common.dart` which is not recommended if you want to keep both a mobile and a web implementation as you would have 2 library with the same name.

A conditionnal import should be done as follow:

```dart
import 'common_mobile.dart'
   if (dart.library.js) 'common.dart' as commonUtils;
```

In this sample I am importing by default the file `common_mobile.dart` but if I am on the web version (which can be verified with `if (dart.library.js)`) I am importing `common.dart`. I am adding the `as commonUtils` keyword to secure my calls to my import.

Now to make a call `myAlert` for example:

```dart
/// Making a web verification to ensure your call is only done when running on web.
if (kIsWeb) {
   /// It should call the myAlert implementation from common.dart
   commonUtils.myAlert('Test');
}
```

Moreover I am seeing that your package does not support mobile which means that if there is build errors related to your package directly you won't be able to build on mobile no matter what you do and your only option is to separate your project into 2 branches (one mobile only and the other one web only) to remove packages that only supports only a specific platform.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. can you please suggest, how we can make 2 branches (one for mobile and another for web? in flutter ? any example will be helpful to understand it thanks

Comment: Of course, when I am talking about branches it concerns your project only if you are already using a software for version management such as Git (GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket). If you are not using this kind of software then I guess you should create a new flutter project which will be dedicated to mobile or web implementation in another directory.

Comment: I am aware about branch concept in version control.  But it looks like a mammoth task. Maybe flutter still not mature enough to take both platform(mobile and web) seamlessly

Comment: This is not about the maturity of Flutter, it is this specific package that has been thinked with web and not mobile in mind. You might want to consider using another package or looking into the base capabilities of Flutter and its `dart:js` library. If you rely that much on this JS package then it might be your project that wasn't thinked to be ported on mobile.